# Find element in table with multiple rows

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to find an element in table with multiple rows,
which is located not on current page.
For example: 
Table of elements that has a limit of 10 elements per page
and the desired element located on 3 page. (elements generated by java script)
How can i get to this element without searching page by page.

Comment: Selenium can only do what you yourself can do in a browser - it just automates the browser. So if you can't see the element in the current page, neither can Selenium. Your test will have to go to the page where it is to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium does not know about other pages, it *works only in the context of the current page*. You would have to go page by page and try searching for the element moving to next page if element is not found.